# Use Reveal.js as npm in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js, reveal.js

I'm working in a project where I have to use Reveal.js in Next.js.
But I don't understand how to do to display the slides. When I try to display, anything appears.

I tried do display some slides but nothing appeared, here's my code:
My component

```
//Slide.js 
import Reveal from 'reveal.js';
import Markdown from 'reveal.js/plugin/markdown/markdown.esm.js';

import '/node_modules/reveal.js/dist/reveal.css';
import '/node_modules/reveal.js/dist/theme/black.css';

Reveal.initialize({
    controls:true,
    width:1000,
    height:1000,
    margin: 0.1,
    display:true,

    plugins: [ Markdown ]

});

export default function Slide(){

    return(
        <>
            <div class="reveal">
            <div class="slides">
                <section>Slide 1</section>
                                  <section data-state="make-it-pop">
                                      <section>Vertical Slide 1</section>
                                      <section>Vertical Slide 2</section>
                                  </section>
                                  <section data-markdown>
                                      <textarea data-template>
                                        ## Slide 1
                                        A paragraph with some text and a [link](http://hakim.se).
                                        ---
                                        ## Slide 2
                                        ---
                                        ## Slide 3
                                      </textarea>
                                  </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>    
    )
}
```

And here the page where it should be displayed:

```
//index.js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const Slide = dynamic(() => import('./slide'), { ssr: false, })

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Slide></Slide>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are importing the reveal.js package, but you are not using it anywhere in your Slide component. You need to use the `Reveal.initialize()` method inside the Slide component to initialize the presentation. This is done inside the
`useEffect` hook.

```
export default function Slide(){
    useEffect(() => {
        Reveal.initialize({
            controls:true,
            width:1000,
            height:1000,
            margin: 0.1,
            display:true,
            plugins: [ Markdownu ]
        });
    }, []);

    return(
    …
```

Comment: I made the changes, but an other error appears: "NoModificationAllowedError: Failed to set the 'outerHTML' property on 'Element': This element has no parent node.". I don't know if you can help me with that